# jupyter lab not opening on jupyter-lab in CMD like in docs

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

In the official jupyter labs installation guide, it says to install jupyter labs with `pip install jupyterlab` and then launch with `jupyter-lab`.

However, what I did was try the first installation method, and when the `jupyter-lab` command to open didn't work, I tried installing again with `python -m pip install jupyterlab`.

Now the `jupyter-lab` command that is listed still isn't recognized, but after playing around, I found that `python -m jupyterlab` opens jupyter labs for me.

1. Why is this?
2. Should I be concerned that I messed anything up, should I just keep using the command that I found, or try to fix my installation so that the official `jupyer-lab` opens the program up?

Thanks

Comment: Try to add Scripts folder inside your installation directory to path

Comment: @RodrigoFerreira And then install it again? Also do you have any idea why the `python -m jupyterlab` command is working right now?

Comment: I usually use `jupyter lab` at the command prompt, with a space between jupyeter and lab.

Comment: I had this same issue, and after hours of troubleshooting found that `python3 -m jupyterlab` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You answered this question in the question, but I'm going to answer it again here and add some context because this problem caused me hours of pain.

```
$ python3 -m jupyterlab
```

This was the command that opened Jupyter Lab for me.

I figured this out after going through a very long process of troubleshooting.

I tried everything described here (and other stuff like installing `brew`) and then tried again after doing a factory reset on my Mac.

I followed [the official instructions](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/installation.html) to install Jupyter Lab with `pip`, which didn't work, but `pip3` did. And I used `$ pip3 show jupyterlab` to identify that the file went to:

```
`/Users/xxx/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages`
```

Immediately I struggled to find the right command to open it.

So I took at look at my PATH (`$ echo "${PATH//:/\n}"`) and realized `/Users` was not in there, so I updated my PATH to include the directory where the download went:

```
`$ export PATH="$PATH:/Users/xxx/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages"`
```

*(Don't ask me what happened when I tried to [follow these instructions to update my bash_profile](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/appleosx-bash-unix-change-set-path-environment-variable/) with the command `vi $HOME/.bash_profile`.)*

When I did this and again entered the command `$ jupyterlab`, the error message changed from: `zsh: command not found: jupyterlab` to `zsh: permission denied: jupyterlab`.

I looked at the permissions for the files in the directory:

```
`$ ls -l /Users/sambrand/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/jupyterlab`
```

It looked to me like I did have read & write access. Still, I tried to change the permissions via the command line, but I received errors I could not totally understand.

I continued to Google and I finally landed on this question. Why is Python environment setup still so hard?